# route() returns different way in two route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I made two resource routes and tied them into a group.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('user/posts', PostController::class)->name('show', 'user.posts');
    Route::resource('admin/posts', PostController::class)->middleware('is_admin')->name('show', 'admin.posts');
});
```

The href tag below code only works in admin, which turns to '/admin/posts'. but when a not admin user is logined, It points '/posts' not '/user/posts'/.

```
<x-jet-nav-link href={{route('posts')}}" :active="request()->routeIs('posts')">
 {{ __('Posts') }}
</x-jet-nav-link>
```

So I had to change the code like below.

```
<x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route(auth()->user()->isAdmin?'admin.posts':'user.posts', '') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('posts')">
 {{ __('Posts') }}
</x-jet-nav-link>
```

what did I miss on the first method?
Additionally `:active=` is not working. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you run `php artisan route:list` and post the output?

And for the second part with the href for the link, I think you need to specify the route like `posts.index` or `posts.show` and for the `isActive` try: `:active="request()->routeIs('posts.*')"`

Comment: here is the output
https://gist.github.com/keshasha/6226ca9eaa2a3bf16e98e8d360497ef7

Comment: Okay, you can see in the output that most of the posts routes are registered twice, once for the admin and once for the user, I suggest you to create Route groups and group the routes for the admin routes and once for the user routes. If you need help with that, let me know and after that with the right route names, the :active attribute should work too.